# Why "time==0.5" isn't a discrete expression in Modelica language?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I build a simple model to understand the concept of "Discrete expressions", here is the code:

```
model Trywhen
  parameter Real B[ :] =   {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
algorithm 
    when time>=0.5 then
      Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print("message");
    end when;
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")));
end Trywhen;
```

But when checking the model, I got an error showing that "time==0.5" isn't a discrete expression.
[image]

[image]

If I change `time==0.5` to `time>=0.5`, the model would pass the check.

[image]

And if I use `if-clause` to `when-clause`, the model works fine but with a warning showing that "Variables of type Real cannot be compared for equality."

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why `time==0.5` is NOT a discrete expression?
2. Why Variables of type Real cannot be compared for equality? It seems common when comparing two variables of type Real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question is not important, since `time==0.5` is not allowed.

The second question is the important one:
Comparing reals for equality is common in other languages, and also a common source of errors - unless special care is taken.

Merely using the floating point compare of the processor is a really bad idea on idea on some processors (like Intel) that mix 80-bit and 64-bit floating point numbers (or comes with a performance penalty), and also in other cases it may not work as intended. In this case 0.5 can be represented as a floating point number, but 0.1 and 0.2 cannot.

Often `abs(x-y)<eps` is a good alternative, but it depends on the intended use and the eps depends on additional factors; not only machine precision but also which algorithm is used to compute x and y and its error propagation.

In Modelica the problems are worse than in many other languages, since tools are allowed to optimize expressions a lot more (including symbolic manipulations) - which makes it even harder to figure out a good value for eps.

All those problems mean that it was decided to not allow comparison for equality - and require something more appropriate.

In particular if you know that you will only approach equality from one direction you can avoid many of the problems. In this case `time` is increasing, so if it has been `>0.5` at an event it will not be `<=0.5` at a later event, and `when` will only trigger the first time the expression becomes true.

Therefore `when time>=0.5` will only trigger once, and will trigger about when time==0.5, so it is a good alternative. However, there might be some numerical inaccuracies and thus it might trigger at 0.500000000000001.

Comment: But `x>=y` still needs to be transformed into the form of "x-y>=eps", so the computer could handle it, right? So how should the machine determine the value of eps when using `x>=y`?

Comment: If it is not optimized into a time event (where we know the exact time it triggers: 5.000), a numerical solver will search for the first time where the condition triggers; this solver will contain its own epsilon value and is probably related to how large time steps you take and what would be considered a tiny value at this point in time. In OpenModelica, the maximum number of iterations is currently `1 + ceil(log(fabs(*b - *a)/(MINIMAL_STEP_SIZE + MINIMAL_STEP_SIZE*fabs(*b-*a)))/log(2))` where b and a are the times to look for zero crossings between (unless the user overrides it)...

Comment: For x>=y we can view it as a binary choice where we want to stay in the previous state (for stability), and the choice of epsilon isn't that critical. One implication is that after changing state then x>=y is (almost certainly) actually correct . That part we cannot guarantee for x==y.